# Listview Pagination Event in Yii2

Tags: listview, yii2

I'm looking for a way to attach some events to new items when they are loaded in the next page of a Listview. In Yii1 it is possible with the property [afterAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CListView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail) of the CListView. After checking the doc, I can not see such a property. Is there a way to achieve this in Yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an hour, I think I could have used the Pjax event. After pagination the Listview is refreshed through pjax.  So I used this:

```
$(document).on('pjax:success', function() {
  // alert("new ListView page loaded");
});
```